# NuxtJS - Integrate PayPal like WooCommerce does

Tags: node.js, woocommerce, paypal, nuxt.js, payment

Moin Moin,

I am currently developing a shop backend with NuxtJS + Express in which the users can later log in to manage their shop (also NuxtJS).

I would now like to integrate PayPal in the same way as WooCommerce does. There, after clicking on a button, you are redirected to PayPal and can log in there. After successful registration, WooCommerce is linked to the PayPal account and when customers pay for the products, the WooCommerce shop owner receives the contributions to his PayPal account.

I searched through the PayPal documentation but didn't really find what I was looking for. But maybe I'm taking the wrong approach. Because even if I do the whole thing using OAuth and save the access token, it expires at some point and has to be renewed and I don't want the shop operator to have to constantly renew their access token in the backend.

I was hoping that someone here might have already done something similar or have some new ideas for me.

I tried to generate an access token with the PayPal Rest API

https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/

But I'm unsure if I am chasing the right solution.

Also I had a look at the JavascriptSDK but this seems more like a frontend integration. You have your own client_id and secret and connect it to one Paypal account. But in my case every user of my app got his own PayPal account with its own credentials.

Greetings from Lübeck

Answer (score 0):

As a PayPal partner, WooCommerce must use something like the [Partner Referrals API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/seller-onboarding/before-payment/).

For platforms that are not PayPal partners, having users copy over their client_id and secret from an app in [the Developer Portal](https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdashboard%2Fapplications&intent=developer) into a config section within an admin panel or similar, is typical.

Comment: So you mean the solution is writing a guide on how to copy the client_id and secret and let them paste them into my backend? :D The problem is, my future customers will be poeple with no computer experience, so I want to make everything as easy as possible.
 
I'll have a look at the Partner Referrals, thank you a lot for that!